# How to implement a wall following controller for a TurtleBot3? (ROS - Python)

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, wheeled-robot, algorithm

I want to implement a wall following controller for my TurtleBot3 (with ROS system).

Sensors which I have on the robot: lidar(360) and optional 2 ultrasonic sensors on the side (one on the left and another one on the right).

Can you recommend me ways the break the mission to tasks and how should I do it? (what's my option to choose from in order to complete the mission)

Comment: start by experimenting

Answer (score 1):

Just check out the bug-algorithms like [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~motionplanning/lecture/Chap2-Bug-Alg_howie.pdf)